# Will it hurt my website's SEO friendliness if I host a french targeted website at, let's say, godaddy.com?

Tags: web, seo, web-hosting

I have read that the server location is important for a website to be SEO friendly. I am planning to build a website from scratch which is targeted mainly to french audience (in France), but I am planning to host the web site at godaddy.com.

My concern is will it hurt the website SEO friendliness? 
Or do you recommend me to host the website in France itself?
I have also read that I need to have a static IP Address. If it's true, can anyone explain me for what reason?

Can anyone suggest me some good web hosting companies, prefereable in France?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/